# Issue installing tidyverse: get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):

Tags: r, tidyverse

I could successfully download `tidyverse` packages but when using
`library(tidyverse)` this message appears:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in get(Info[i,
> 1], envir = env): No such file or directory.

I have the latest version of RStudio

Comment: How exactly did you install the tidyverse? Were there any errors or warnings at all during that process? What version of R are you using?

Comment: You can also try closing all running instances of R and try again.

Comment: have you installed the tidyverse with install.packages("tidyverse")?

Comment: have you installed the tidyverse with install.packages("tidyverse")?
- Yes, I did

I closed and opened R multiple times, but still the message appears.

How exactly did you install the tidyverse? Were there any errors or warnings at all during that process? What version of R are you using
- WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding. This message appears too

Answer (score 0):

1. Session -> Restart R
2. Check the version of R that you use via `version`. If it is not 3.6.3 or 4.0.0, reinstall R from the official project website (https://www.r-project.org/).
3. Check your library path with `.libPaths()`. If folders like 'dplyr' are not in there, you have not installed the package properly.
4. Install Tidyverse via `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

You can also check the installed packages using the 'Packages' tab on the lower right panel in RStudio.